# jQuery Hero-Slider back and forth

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I tried to make a little slideshow for a hero header using javascript.
It should slide up to the last image and than slide back in the opposite direction.
It works, but ONLY if all the three duration numbers are exactly the same.

Does anybody know why or what I could change?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var slider = $("#hero-slider");
var slides = slider.find(".hero-slides");
var sliderWidth = $("#hero-slider").width();
var slideCount = $(".hero-slide").length;
var currentSlide = 1;

setInterval(function() {
    if(currentSlide === 1){
        slides.animate({
        "margin-left": "-=" + sliderWidth
    }, 2000, function(){
        currentSlide++;
    });
    } else if(currentSlide === slideCount) {
        slides.animate({
        "margin-left": "+=" + sliderWidth
    }, 2000, function(){
        currentSlide--;
    });
    };
}, 2000);
});
```

-

```
<div id="hero-slider">
    <ul class="hero-slides">
        <li class="hero-slide"><img src="img/slide-1.jpg"></li>
        <li class="hero-slide"><img src="img/slide-2.jpg"></li>
        <li class="hero-slide"><img src="img/slide-3.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```